# How do I revert to controller based identity and authentication in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I would like to use a Controller based Identity with .NET Core 2.1. I would like to scaffold the UI but the scaffolder creates Razor Page based identity. I would like to use controllers instead of Razor Pages. Is it possible to scaffold this?

Comment: For `Scaffold Identity`, it only provides `Razor Page`, if you prefer `AccountController`, you need to implement your own controller and view.

Comment: I found that creating a new project and choosing the.net core V2 as the .net version will create the controller based authentication vs the razor one.

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a new project and choosing the.net core V2 with authentication will create the controller based authentication vs the razor one.